# Can a function $f:\mathbb{R^n} \mapsto \mathbb{R^m}$ where $n<m$ be surjective?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-set-theory

I have thought about the following problem: We have a function $f$, which has as the domain $A \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ and maps its inputs to a higher dimensional space $B \subseteq \mathbb{R^m}$ where it is strictly $n < m$. Can this function be onto (surjective) where it exhausts all members of its codomain $B$ such that each $b \in B$ is mapped from a $a \in A$? For example we can have a function $f:\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m}$ where $n < m$, $f(u)=(x_1(u),x_2(u),\dots,x_m(u))$ with each of the $m$ coordinates is determined by $u \in \mathbb{R^n}$. Such a function should cover only a $n$ dimensional surface or collection of surfaces in $\mathbb{R^m}$ according to my intuition but I cannot show this. Is this intuition true? How can it be shown more or less formally, if it is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can even be bijective. Look at the [space-filling curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) for dimensions $1$ and $2$.

But you cannot have it ***injective*** **and** ***continuous*** if $m \neq n$. This is easy to prove if we only talk about diffeomorphisms (because then the differential $df$ is a linear isomorphism from $R^n$ to $R^m$ which implies $n=m$) but is a really tough result in the realm of continuous functions (see [this paper](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/jordan/dieujord.pdf)).